# How can I set a new variable with each iteration of a loop (setting part of file name as column headers through concatenation)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, variables

I am running re-sampling on a set of files within a folder using a loop and then concatenating them to make a new, wide dataframe. As standard, the concatenation returns generic 'value' entries for each of the new columns and I'd like to set part of the concatenated filenames as variables so that I can then call them to populate the column names.

To iterate through the list and get the first eight characters of the file names (which I would like to set as variables) I use the following code:

```py
for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):

        print(filename[:8])
```

This prints the file names (e.g. 202_3983) as a proof of concept, but I'm not sure about how to create a unique variable with each iteration (e.g. col1 = '202_3983', col2 = '202_3984', etc.)

I then use the following for the concatenation:

```py
df = pd.concat(
            [pd.read_csv(f).set_index('logtime_round') for f in glob.glob('*.csv')],
            axis=1).reset_index()
```

Perhaps with something like the following to add the new variables as names to the columns:

```py
df.columns = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5] # as many col* as there are columns
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few hours more of work, I was able to find a working solution (however, any comments on better practice much appreciated!)

```py
    # Create list of files in the root directory for renaming columns
    cols = os.listdir(root_dir)

    # Manipulate list to create new list with only first 8 characters
    col8 = [c[:8] for c in cols]

    # Rename columns within dataframe using the specified strings
    df.columns = col8
```